# MOSS 2007 Migrating to MS Server 2008 64-bit

Tags: windows-server-2008, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint

So we just got our new beefy sharepoint box that we will be using as a replacement for our Web Front End/Index Server and I want to put a 64-bit version of Server 2008 on it and I looking for info on what to watch out for.

I found a few issues thus far but what else have you guys run into?

Installing MOSS and getting a compatablity error:
http://edge.technet.com/Media/Installing-MOSS-2007-on-Windows-Server-2008/

Developing workflows on server looks like they crash: 
http://sharepointsharpener.wordpress.com/2009/01/12/developing-workflows-not-possible-on-64-bit-sharepoint/

This guy seems to have run into a few little issues:
http://msmvps.com/blogs/shane/archive/2009/01/05/prepare-for-the-future-windows-2008-and-64bit.aspx

Any big things I should be looking for ?

Thanks for the help,

Chris

Answer (score 1):

If you have any 3rd party components, such as web parts, make sure that they are not limited to 32bit operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

In our environment, we upgrading a x86 WFE server to a x64 server. Although we did not upgrade to Windows Server 2008, it may be comforting for you to know that we didn't encounter any major issues with regard to x64 compatibility.

The main hurdle was ensuring all of our custom application code was recompiled to x64. Also bear in mind that you will need to ensure all servers at a particular tier (e.g. WFE, application, DB) should be of the same architecture (i.e. x86 or x64).

I'm not sure if it will be useful to you, but I have recently posted instructions on how to go about upgrading an x86 SQL server running server 2003 to an x64 server running server 2008. Check it out at http://mossblogger.blogspot.com/ if you are interested.

I would be interested to know if you encounter any issues - HTH.

Cheers, Ben.